# The redirect URI in the request, https://localhost:44322/domain.com, does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, model-view-controller

I am getting this error when I run the application locally, without doing anything it gives me the error on the first page. Here is the screenshot of the error. [image: The redirect URI in the request, https://localhost:44322/domain.com, does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client. To update the authorized redirect URIs].

```
The redirect URI in the request, https://localhost:44322/domain.com, does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client. To update the authorized redirect URIs
```

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to authorize your localhost redirect url in google account configuration

> In the Authorized redirect URIs text entry box, set the redirect URI.
> For example, https://localhost:44312/signin-google

You can read more about it here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/google-logins?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: thanks for the replay but what if I want to do something like "https://localhost:44312/myDomain.com", is it possible?

Comment: look at the [Change the default callback URI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/google-logins?view=aspnetcore-3.1#change-the-default-callback-uri)